# CSS Layout - How to order elements based on on wrapping rather than viewport width?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

A common problem we deal with on our team is laying out a header that has some icons on the left, a main title, and a couple of options on the right side.

I want to work out a responsive approach to this using Flexbox, CSS Grid, or anything else that would work.

I've experimented the most with Flexbox and have not been able to get it to work.

Here is the structure and how I would like things to wrap as the screen gets narrower (regardless of width breakpoints).

[image: Header with a Primary element in the middle and secondary elements on each side.]

The HTML for this would be something like this.

```
<div class="responsive-header">
    <div class="secondary slot-1">Secondary Slot 1</div>
    <div class="primary">Primary Slot</div>
    <div class="secondary slot-2">Secondary Slot 2</div>
</div>
```

For Flexbox, the CSS might be something like this.

```
.responsive-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .primary {
        flex: 2 1 auto;
        min-width: 10rem;
        text-align: center;
        order: 2;
    }
    .secondary {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        min-width: 3rem;
        max-width: 8rem;

        &.slot-1 { text-align: left; order: 1; }
        &.slot-2 { text-align: right; order: 3; }
    }
}
```

This, however, results in Slot 1 always being on top when the header wraps.

I know how to use the `order` attribute to change things around with media query breakpoints, but I'd rather have this be a fluid adjustment based on available space.

ETA: [CodePen to play with](https://codepen.io/scottmcd-the-vuer/pen/BazLZEK?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1):

I am not that experienced with CSS but I believe you can not achieve such thing without any media queries or JS. Don't forget browsers use 'Cascading Style Sheets'. Meaning, they render things as they read code from the top to the bottom.

Changing the order of the elements would require at least some sort of media query althought flex and grid can do wonders they are not that smart. I do hope that I am wrong and someone could show us some grid solution but why dont you do this instead:

1. Remove the `order:` from all elements and let the browser order them
   based on the markup
2. On the desired width add `order:-1;` to your primary container that would send it to the beginning of the container no matter what

```css
.responsive-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .primary {
    flex: 2 1 auto;
    min-width: 10rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .secondary {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width: 3rem;
    max-width: 8rem;
    &.slot-1 {
      text-align: left;
    }
    &.slot-2 {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .primary {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-header">
  <div class="secondary slot-1">Secondary Slot 1</div>
  <div class="primary">Primary Slot</div>
  <div class="secondary slot-2">Secondary Slot 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I'm afraid you're right that it may not be possible.  Knowing for sure though would still be helpful.  I'd forgotten about setting the order to -1, cool!  If you use the right minimum widths along with a media-query, you might be able to simulate the effect I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Flex will only be useful in the wide screen view (note that the elements order was swapped). For the mid-size screen, you need to float the secondary elements. For the small screen default to natural block rendering.

```css
.responsive-header,
.primary,
.secondary {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.primary {
  background-color: #fcd6b9;
}

.slot-1 {
  background-color: #e6e6c5;
}

.slot-2 {
  background-color: #d5ecfd;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .responsive-header {
    display: flex;
  }
  .primary {
    order: 2;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .secondary {
    float: none !important;
    width: 80px !important;
  }

  .slot-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .slot-2 {
    order: 3;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .secondary {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-header">
    <div class="primary">Primary Slot</div>
    <div class="secondary slot-1">Secondary Slot 1</div>
    <div class="secondary slot-2">Secondary Slot 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, no suggestions on doing it without media queries?

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible without media queries, specially since you are swapping the order of things in one of the views.